# Use facebook login in localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am doing a project and need to use the facebook API as user login.
The document are clear the usage of the login button of login with facebook.
However, when I test the button on localhost, it gives nothing to me, no error page, no popup windows.

I am using xampp for my local development and the site url that I fill in app setting is `http://localhost:8880/atrain/`

can someone help? I have searched the internet and change the hosts file but still unsuccessful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Facebook application on localhost](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your local server to use the standard http port (80) and use a virtual host with a [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain). It can be a fake TLD such as:

```
localhost.dev
```

How you actually accomplish this depends on what type of web-server you are using.