# session codeigniter localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, localhost

I'm using [this Facebook lib](https://github.com/coolcflame87/Facebook-v4-PHP-CodeIgniter) for CodeIgniter so users can login with Facebook. Works perfectly fine on production, but not on localhost. The thing that is bugging me is that it used to work fine on localhost, but suddenly stopped working.

I've been searching for some time and I'm expecting that this has something to do with CI's session library, but I'm not 100% sure.

**Background info**

- I'm running MAMP with PHP 5.5.10 and Chrome 41.0.2272.118
- Locally I've configured the httpd.conf in MAMP so my local url is a 'real' URL like www.example-local.net and Apache port is 80
- `if($this->session)` in a view returns true. EDIT; I don't actually use this in a view but it's just to test that this is working
- The production and development code are exactly the same, except for the Facebook API key and secret since I use a test app locally. As indicated; it worked perfectly fine before and I haven't changed my test app settings.
- EDIT: I have my TLD configured as app domain and site URL in the FB test app. Again, this doesn't seem to be the issue since

**The problem**

- `if($this->session)` in the (Facebook) library file returns false. EDIT; this seems to be the issue. So this is working in the view, not in the library. The weird thing about it is that this was working before (no code change)
- It also seems that therefore the library doesn't set `fb_boken` in the session userdata and that's why I suspect there's something wrong with setting `$this->session`
- I did move to a different timezone (just 1 hour) and I read somewhere that this could cause issues? EDIT; I've been back in the timezone where it worked previously and it's still not working

**What I already tried and did not work**

- In `config.php` setting `$config['sess_expiration']` to a high value (eg 999999) instead of 7200
- In `config.php` changing `$config['cookie_domain']` to the localhost website (`http://www.example-local.net`, tried with and without trailing slash) instead of empty ("")
- In `config.php` changing `$config['sess_match_useragent']` to `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`
- Replace app/system/library/Session.php with PHP's native session as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299433/native-session-modified-for-code-igniter-2-1-4-does-this-make-sense)
- Clear all my cookies and browsing data

**Additional info on config.php**

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

I hoped that using PHP's native session would resolve the problem, but it didn't. Not sure what else I can try.

**For reference the full Facebook.php library file code**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
    session_start();
}

require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );

use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

class Facebook {
    var $ci;
    var $helper;
    var $session;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();

        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $this->ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook'), $this->ci->config->item('app_secret', 'facebook') );
        $this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $this->ci->config->item('redirect_url', 'facebook') );

        if ( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') ) {
            $this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') );

            // Validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
            try {
                if ( ! $this->session->validate() ) {
                  $this->session = false;
                }
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                // Catch any exceptions
                $this->session = false;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                $this->session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
            } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
                // When Facebook returns an error
            } catch(\Exception $ex) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
            }
        }

        if ( $this->session ) {
            $this->ci->session->set_userdata( 'fb_token', $this->session->getToken() );

            $this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->session->getToken() );
        }
    }


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

    public function get_login_url() {
        return $this->helper->getLoginUrl( $this->ci->config->item('permissions', 'facebook') );
    }


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Logout URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

    public function get_logout_url() {
        if ( $this->session ) {
            return $this->helper->getLogoutUrl( $this->session, site_url() );
        }
        return false;
    }


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Get user data
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

    public function get_user() {
        if ( $this->session ) {
            try {
                $user = (new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

                return $user;

            } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
                return false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957218/use-facebook-login-in-localhost

Comment: I use a virtual host with a TLD, so my local domain is www.example-local.net

Comment: Just checked, I'm also on port 80. So that can't be the issue.

Comment: i found CIv2 sessions class to fail - esp. with ajax - did you try and use PHP's $_SESSION variable instead?

Comment: When you say it isnt working what exactly is happening (or not)?

Comment: What is the error? Do you have to whitelist your test domain on facebook? Have you tried changing your computers timezone / PHP timezone to the previous one?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. And update: pgee70; see point 4 under 'what I already tried'. This is not working. Mike I've update the question to describe the problem better, hope this is more clear now. @SamV I've updated the question to describe the problem better, hope this is more clear now. I've also added how I added my test domain in the FB test app. As indicated, this worked before so this doesn't seem the issue. I'm also back in the 'original' timezone, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I am working on same plugin. Thank god, after 2 days of effort its working fine. If you can reach me out someone, I will be glad to assist you. I am in the process of building a git for this. But that requires some time too. I might be able to give you exact answer if we could chat for a while!

Comment: check session destroyed when you are working with production. And check also Facebook App setting

Comment: @eskimo have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @IbeVanmeenen No I haven't. Still the same problem, it turns out if I reload a couple of times eventually it works, but it seems very random.

Comment: @IbeVanmeenen if you have the same problem or any ideas about a solution please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @eskimo no solution yet, but will look into it later on. I'll definitely post the solution here if found.

Answer (score 3):

The library you are using is external to the core CodeIgniter codebase and therefore isn't able to communicate with native functions in the normal way; instead of using `$this` as your reference to the CodeIgniter instance, in your library you should be using `$this->ci` so to access session data, your code would look something like:

```
$this->ci->session->userdata();
```

This is explained in more detail in the CodeIgniter documentation [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html)

Comment: It still doesn't work if I replace all instances of `$this->session` with `$this->ci->session` in the Facebook.php library. If I do this what also happens is that `if($this->session)` in the view returns false, while if I keep the Facebook.php library code like it is now (as in my post) this returns true in the view.

Answer (score 0):

in the view use `$this->facebook->session` instead of `$this->session` and it will work ;)

Comment: Thanks. This is not the issue, in the view `$this->session` is working (I updated the question to indicate I don't actually use it in the view but it was just to test if it would return true which it does). The problem is that `$this->session` is not working in the library.